# How to divide array results inside a foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a simple Select query in WordPress PHP, that selects all results from a database table, and I print the results on a page using the basic foreach, shown below:

```
$newest = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_refundrequests WHERE state = 'Odottavat' ORDER BY
  request_date DESC", ARRAY_A);
  foreach ($newest as $row) {
   echo "Product names: " . $row['product_name'];
}
```

My "product_name" column has multiple product names however, since I have inserted them as an array earlier. Here is an example of the data I have in my table:

[image]

But I would like to print all of these names on new lines, so the results would be something along the lines of:

```
Product one 
Product two
Product three
```

..etc etc, is there a way to do this? I tried to do this with some  tags, but that didn't work.

Comment: is that an array or text ?

Comment: @Mynameis The database value should be an array

Comment: `$products = explode('","', $row['product_name'])` - but you should better store them seperately already.

Comment: @Jeff Did this and then tried to echo the "$products", but gives me an notice "Array to string conversion", and doesn't print anything else than just "Array"

Comment: explode creates an array. you can't `echo` an array you can `var_dump` or `print_r `though.

Comment: Ahh makes sense, however this didn't print them on their own lines, they are still just on the same line :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
foreach ($newest as $row) {
    $products = explode('","', $row['product_name']);
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $product = trim($product); // not necessary
        echo "Product name: " . $product . "</br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't put them on new lines either. :/ The trim command was a nice touch though!

Comment: How you output this name? If via html - add `echo "Product name: " . $product . "</br>";`

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense, it works now! Thank you very much! :P

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
<?php

    $items = "item1,item2,item3"; // $row['product_name']
    $item = explode(",", $items);
    echo $item[0];

?>
```

Comment: What if there is a comma `,` inside the product name?

Comment: It's already a mistake that 1 cell has more than 1 values so honestly i don't see any other way. If there is a `,` it will create a wrong output but this problem occurs by the fact that the data is inserted wrong in the db. I consider above answer as the only "solution" to this.

Comment: This still doesn't print them in new lines, otherwise it prints the results fine :/